# Why $\int_{- \infty} ^\infty x e^{-ax^2}dx=0$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, gaussian-integral

I really don't understand why $\int_{- \infty} ^\infty x e^{-ax^2}dx=0$.

I can see $x e^{-ax^2}$ as $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{e^{-ax^2}}{-2a}$ that, integrated, is clearly different from 0...

Comment: "that, integrated, is clearly different from 0" Hmmm... Using the remark in your post yields, **assuming that $a$ is positive**, $$\int_{- \infty} ^\infty x e^{-ax^2}dx=\left.\frac{e^{-ax^2}}{-2a}\right|_{-\infty}^\infty=\frac{0}{-2a}-\frac{0}{-2a}$$ which is "clearly" $0$, no?

Comment: @Did you are right! In my sheet I made the mistake of not removing the integration symbol after the integration.... and so....... many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without calculating nothing directly, you can seet that the function is symmteric with respect to the origin.

If you want a formal answer, you can split the integral into two integrals (you can do it because you know both of them converge):

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-ax^2}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{0}xe^{-ax^2}dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-ax^2}dx$

and then change variables in the left integral $x\to -x$ and you will get zero.

Comment: but why I can't see the integrand function as the derivative of $e^{-ax^2}$?

Comment: You can do it after you split the integral, and you will get zero as well

Comment: No need to split for that.

Comment: Pedagogically, you should split, otherwise you can do things like "$\int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}xdx=0$"

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, we can answer the question in the following cumbersome way:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{-ax^2} dx
&=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2+tx}dx \Big|_{t=0}\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a(x-t/(2a))^2}dx\, e^{t^2/(4a)}\Big|_{t=0}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\frac{d}{dt}e^{t^2/(4a)}\Big|_{t=0}\\
&=0\,.
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=xe^{-ax^2}$ is an odd function.

Thus, $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx=0$